# Missing Monero Funds

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, monero-wallet-gui, monero-research-lab, monero-club

I made a transaction on ShapeShift. The transaction was successful but I never received my funds in my wallet. I’ve already talked with ShapeShift customer and they said the best thing to do is to ask you guys here get in touch with the dev team of the Monero wallet. (I’m using CLI and GUI)
I transferred Bitcoin to Monero as you can see here: https://shapeshift.io/#/status/996fe4c5-7d64-40ac-bf0b-4baaaec7fb42

My Tx hash: 7eb429acae351049713f8bac3ce9e1519cc76e6181b9ab3f5285949063110747

The transaction posted to the blockchain here: https://moneroblocks.info/search/7eb429acae351049713f8bac3ce9e1519cc76e6181b9ab3f5285949063110747

Using the xmrchain I can see that my Monero was sent to an output.
However, I’m seeing 0 balance in my wallet. I’m using the Monero GUI wallet (version 0.10.3.1 – beta2). I also tried using the monero CLI (version 0.10.3.1), and still 0 balance.
What's wrong?
Can anyone help?
Thanks…

Comment: Is your daemon in sync with the blockchain?

Comment: @assylias yes pls.

Comment: @dcrew Are you sure you are in sync? This follow up question of yours seems to imply the opposite: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4074/monero-height-at-a-standstill

Comment: I thought I was. Till someone told me abt my height

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that your transaction is in the block chain and your monerod is synchronize 100% type the following in the CLI wallet. This will rescan the blockchain to check your own transactions.

```
rescan_bc
```

If you are not sure if you are 100% synchronize type the following in monerod

```
status
```

Comment: I just did both, "rescan _bc & status" but still 0 balance.

Comment: Did you click the "see it on the blockchain" link?  Do that, and then paste in your address and private viewkey into that site (xmrchain.net, midway down)) to verify that your wallet owns the outputs generated and sent by shapeshift.

Comment: status   Height: 335459/335459 (100.0%) on mainnet

Comment: Did you run "rescan _bc" on the CLI wallet? Can you also double check your address if it is the same as 44sT9wE7x7... Lastly in your CLI wallet type show_transfers .. see if there are incoming/outgoing transfers.