# Monero Height at a standstill

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, blockchain, full-node, mining-pools, synchronization

My Height seems to be stuck here 335459/335459 (100.0%) on mainnet

But when I check the current height online it's 1289240

Could someone help me?

Comment: Which version of Monero are you runnining and what is your operating system? If you recently upgraded from an old version it may help to re-sync from scratch

Comment: Windows 10 , Monero v0.10.3.1

Comment: exit monerod, and restart it with "--log-level 1", then it will tell you why it fails to add blocks once it receives them.

Answer (score 6):

The 100% part of the message means that you are connected only to nodes with at most that height, which is far in the past.

Try `print_cn` and see if you have any peers, and how many. This is odd that you'd be connected to only bad peers.

To try to fix the problem:

- exit monerod
- remove ~/.bitmonero/p2pstate.bin
- start monerod again

This will cause monerod to start picking new peers, and hopefully pick at least one good one this time.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.
It was my school wifi...
I'm not able to sync with the blockchain when using school wifi but when I tried a different source of internet the blockchain was syncing...

Is there a way around it?
Is there something I can do so I utilise my school internet to be able to access my monero?